# Running code through a function without losing scope in PHP

Tags: php

This year, I set myself the challenge of doing the Advent of Code challenges using strict out-of-the-box PHP (masochism, I know). For the most part, it worked out really well, but I encountered a couple of issues where I'm not entirely sure how best to do what it is I want to do.

Say I have a couple of places in my code where I'm trying to optimize for performance, and I've written things like:

```
function rutime($ru, $rus, $index) {
    return ($ru["ru_$index.tv_sec"]*1000 + intval($ru["ru_$index.tv_usec"]/1000))
     -  ($rus["ru_$index.tv_sec"]*1000 + intval($rus["ru_$index.tv_usec"]/1000));
}

$ruStart = getrusage();
$array   = array_fill(1,1000000,'1');
$ruEnd   = getrusage();
echo 'Built array in ', rutime($ruEnd, $ruStart, 'utime'), 'ms. ', PHP_EOL;

$ruStart = getrusage();
unset($array[456789]);
unset($array[567890]);
unset($array[678901]);
$ruEnd   = getrusage();
echo 'Unset three values in ', rutime($ruEnd, $ruStart, 'utime'), 'ms. ', PHP_EOL;

$ruStart = getrusage();
$count   = count($array);
$ruEnd   = getrusage();
echo 'Counted array size (', $count, ') in ', rutime($ruEnd, $ruStart, 'utime'), 'ms. ', PHP_EOL;

$ruStart = getrusage();
$array   = array_values($array);
$ruEnd   = getrusage();
echo 'Renumbered array in ', rutime($ruEnd, $ruStart, 'utime'), 'ms. ', PHP_EOL;

$ruStart = getrusage();
$count   = count($array);
$ruEnd   = getrusage();
echo 'Counted array size (', $count, ') in ', rutime($ruEnd, $ruStart, 'utime'), 'ms. ', PHP_EOL;
```

Now, the output from here will tell me how fast the various things I did were, but there is a **lot** of repeated code that I really want to avoid.

What I'm trying to do is to build a function that will parse my code and run it, give me output, and never once lose scope, no matter what it is I'm running through it. Imagine something like:

`showRunTime("$array = array_fill(1,1000000,'1');");`

What I would want this function to do is to actually create the array and have it available for the next line, which might just be `print_r($array);` or something similar, but I want the function to actually output what it is that I'm doing. The obvious:

```
function showRunTime($command) {
  $ruStart = getrusage();
  eval($command);
  $ruEnd = getrusage();
  echo rutime($ruEnd, $ruStart, 'utime');
}
```

Won't work, obviously, since `eval()` doesn't have the right scope for what is in the command. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: One would think, but even something like `call_user_func('getRunTime', "\$array = array_fill(1,1000000,'1');");` will not allow me to access the contents of $array later in the code since it's only created inside the function when evaluated.

Comment: What's the problem? Just declare it global.

Comment: No. No, no, no, no no. I have no idea that `$array` will be used the next time I want to use `showRunTime()`. I might be using a completely different variable or array, and I don't want to have to put my entire variable scope into global.

Comment: That's what namespaces are for. But if that bothers you, and the only thing stopping you from scraping the function for making things neat in the first place, you might try setting a variable to the contents of the function, then run all of your code through eval. Ultimately this would achieve C/C++ style macros so you could just insert the variable directly into the string being evaluated to "run" the macro for generating the string you need for eval to call.